# How to make django-filters works in Embedded Model Field?

Tags: python, django, filter

For example, the models.py looks like this:

```
class Locations(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    fendering_position = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    STS_position = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    STS_latitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    STS_longitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

class EmergencyContacts(models.Model):
    Oil_Spill_Responders = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Local_Emergency_Medical_Assistance = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Police = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)

class Equipment_Details(models.Model):
    Primary_Fenders = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Secondary_Fenders = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    Fender_Moorings = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)

class LocationsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Locations
        fields = [
            'name', 'fendering_position', 'STS_position', 'STS_latitude', 'STS_longitude', ]


class EmergencyContactsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmergencyContacts
        fields = [
            'Oil_Spill_Responders', 'Local_Emergency_Medical_Assistance', 'Police']


class Equipment_DetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Equipment_Details
        fields = [
            'Primary_Fenders', 'Secondary_Fenders', 'Fender_Moorings']

class Entry(models.Model):

    locations = models.EmbeddedModelField(
        model_container=(Locations),
        model_form_class=LocationsForm
    )

    emergencycontacts = models.EmbeddedModelField(
        model_container=(EmergencyContacts),
        model_form_class=EmergencyContactsForm
    )

    equipment_details = models.EmbeddedModelField(
        model_container=(Equipment_Details),
        model_form_class=Equipment_DetailsForm
    )
```

and now everything will store in the Entry table, so if I want to use django-filters to search, what should I do? I try:

```
class EntryFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
     name = CharFilter(field_name='name', lookup_expr='icontains') 

 class Meta:
        model = Entry.locations  
        fields = 'name'
```

and this does not work, I also try:

```
class Meta:
    model = Entry
    fields = '__all__'
```

and this also does not work, so what should I write on the filters.py to make it can search for the locations name, Oil_Spill_Responders, and Primary_Fenders.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code once

```py
from .models import Locations

class EntryFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
     name = CharFilter(field_name='name', lookup_expr='icontains') 

     class Meta:
          model = Locations
          fields = ["name"]
```

**NOTE:** when you want to pass all the fields

```py
 class Meta:
          model = Locations
          fields = "__all__"
```

**NOTE:** when you are passing selected fields pass them in a list

```py
 class Meta:
          model =  Locations
          fields = ["field_1", "field_2", ...]
```

Comment: No, it cannot work, it will show that Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field. Choices are: id, locations.... which are all the models which inside of the Entry